# How to install MongoDB with Ansible?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ansible

I'm a beginner with Ansible and I'm now trying to install MongoDB on an Ubuntu 14.04 host. According to the [MongoDB installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) the manual process is as follows:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I guess I can run this using the Ansible shell module, but since line 2 of the 4 lines about would constantly add new lines to the `mongodb-org-3.6.list` file I guess that is not the correct way.

Does anybody know what the logical way of doing this with Ansible is? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create your mongo-ansible.yml file and use this:

```
# Install mongodb 
---
- name: Add mongo ppa key
  sudo: yes
  apt_key: >
    keyserver=hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
    id=7F0CEB10
    state=present
- name: Add mongo sources list
  sudo: yes
  lineinfile: >
    line="deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse"
    dest=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
    state=present
    create=yes
- name: Install mongo
  sudo: yes
  apt: name=mongodb-org state=latest update_cache=yes
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask why you install `mongodb-10gen` instead of `mongodb-org`?

Comment: Well you can use mongodb-org instead :) I used to use 10gen back in the old days but now as you can stick to org one.

Comment: You should use [apt_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_repository_module.html) instead of `lineinfile`.

Answer (score 11):

In that case you don't even have to mess with `lineinfile`. Use the `apt_repository` module ([documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_repository_module.html)) ; in this example we'll install MongoDB 3.4:

```
  [...]
  tasks:
   - name: Add Mongo packages repo
     apt_key: id=2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5  keyserver=keyserver.ubuntu.com
   - name: add repo itself
     apt_repository: repo='deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu {{ansible_distribution_release}}/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse' state=present                                      
   - name: install packages
     apt: pkg=mongodb-org state=present
  [...]
```

Answer (score 5):

In ansible 2.0 `sudo` deprecated and [`block`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) added. So for modern syntax and latest mongodb:

```
---
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
- block:
  - name: Import MongoDB public GPG Key
    apt_key:
        keyserver: keyserver.ubuntu.com
        id: 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
  - name: Add MongoDB repository into sources list
    apt_repository:
        repo: deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu {{ansible_distribution_release}}/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse
        state: present
  - name: Install MongoDB package
    apt:
        name: mongodb-org
        update_cache: yes
  become: yes
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to do this by using shell commands. [apt_key](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_key_module.html) module can add keys, [apt](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html) module can be used to install and [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module can ensure a particular line in file.

```
- name: get apt key
  apt_key: keyserver=hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 id=EA312927

- name: add to mongodb-org-3.2.list
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list line="deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse"

- name: install mongo db
  apt: name=mongodb-org update_cache=yes
```

If you need to create `mongodb-org-3.2.list` first then you can use [file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) module for that.

```
- name: create mongodb-org-3.2.list
  file: path=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list state=present
```